# Stop Keil uVision build when warning detected

Tags: build, keil

I am building a project with `Keil uV5.17`. The build stops when it detects an error, however I would like to have the same behavior with a warning.
Currently I am using an **Option for Target** >> **User** >> **Stop on Exit Code**. However it seems to ignore warnings, any options on how to stop the build, when a warning appears?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the warnings to be treated as error, go to the Options for target>>C/C++. In the Misc controls add:

```
--diag_error=warning
```